# Out of memory with tomcat 6 on RedHat but not in debian

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay

I am using liferay 6.0.6 with tomcat 6 and using terracotta 3.5.4.
The terracotta installation in on another server and works fine.

The debian and redhat systems are virtual machines and use the exact same virtual hardware.
1 cpu , 4gb ram, both 64bit OS.

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (rhel-1.48.1.11.3.el6_2-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

If im using a debian system and boot the application then it everything works as expected.

If im using the redhat system then i get an error :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:657)
    at java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:176)
    at com.tc.object.locks.ClientLockManagerImpl.<init>(ClientLockManagerImpl.java:39)
    at com.tc.object.StandardDSOClientBuilder.createLockManager(StandardDSOClientBuilder.java:190)
    at com.tc.object.DistributedObjectClient.start(DistributedObjectClient.java:639)
    at com.tc.object.bytecode.ManagerImpl$2.execute(ManagerImpl.java:263)
    at com.tc.lang.StartupHelper.startUp(StartupHelper.java:39)
    at com.tc.object.bytecode.ManagerImpl.startClient(ManagerImpl.java:281)
    at com.tc.object.bytecode.ManagerImpl.init(ManagerImpl.java:202)
    at com.tc.object.bytecode.ManagerImpl.init(ManagerImpl.java:190)
    at com.tc.object.bytecode.hook.impl.DSOContextImpl.createStandaloneContext(DSOContextImpl.java:179)
    at org.terracotta.express.StandaloneL1Boot.call(StandaloneL1Boot.java:190)
    at org.terracotta.express.ClientImpl.<init>(ClientImpl.java:309)
    at org.terracotta.express.ClientFactoryImpl.newClient(ClientFactoryImpl.java:232)
    at org.terracotta.express.ClientFactoryImpl.createClient(ClientFactoryImpl.java:225)
    at org.terracotta.express.ClientFactoryImpl.createClient(ClientFactoryImpl.java:212)
    at org.terracotta.express.ClientFactoryImpl.getOrCreateClient(ClientFactoryImpl.java:190)
    at org.terracotta.express.ClientFactory.getOrCreateClient(ClientFactory.java:28)
    at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.StandaloneTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.<init>(StandaloneTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

The weirdest part of this error is that memory is not used.
I have set the Xmx at 3500m but the memory usage never climbs above 2.3gb.

I've been searching for a possible cause and found this :
[Low Java single process thread limit in Red Hat Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116640/low-java-single-process-thread-limit-in-red-hat-linux)

So i changed my ulimit -n and ulimit -u to 80000 but still nothing changes.

I then edited my /etc/security/limits.conf

```
*       soft    nproc           81920
*       hard    nproc           81920
*       soft    nofile          81920
*       hard    nofile          81920
```

I also edited /etc/sysctl.conf

```
fs.file-max = 100000
```

then i rebooted.

I also added -Xms=2g to my setenv.sh

I increased -Xss to -Xss5000k

I run echo 200000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max

But the same error still comes up. Any ideas ?

free -m at begining of booting

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3963       1027       2935          0         25        748
-/+ buffers/cache:        253       3709
Swap:         2047         18       2029
```

free -m just before crash

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3963       2897       1065          0         31        823
-/+ buffers/cache:       2043       1920
Swap:         2047         18       2029
```

Update : i also tried with a machine with 8gb ram and the same result appears.

Comment: Are the JREs identical ?   Can you post your  *free -m*  output for the RHT machine  ?

Comment: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (rhel-1.48.1.11.3.el6_2-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: For lack of better options, I'd consider upgrading to JRE 7, possibly even Hotspot instead of Openjdk.

Comment: JRE7 will not work with the application. I also tried to use the sun jdk 1.6 but i get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java process contains several memory pool. [java memory structure](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-sP7by9zlbVQ/TaZ5LIfRxdI/AAAAAAAAAmg/diXDFa64OTo/s1600/MemoryStructure.png)

In your case OutOfMemory error say: no enough space in your Java Process for stack allocation.

- So if you increase *-Xss* pool you are able to start less threads
  count in your application. Try to decrease *-Xss* parameters. Thread
  with big stack you are able to start with [special constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String,%20long%29).
- Also you are able to decrease memory for heap, because the more
  memory is allocated for the heap (not necessarily used by the heap),
  the less memory available in the stack.
- Or even better try to review your application structure and decrease
  thread count in your application, using ThreadPool or e.t.c.

Comment: i tried as you described. JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Duser.timezone=Europe/Paris -Xss512k -Xmx2g -Xms1g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" but this gives the save error as before. Please note that this boots fine in ubuntu but not in redhat.

Comment: So i decreased the Xss value even further to 256k. (128kb gives me a overflow error ). This gives me the exact same error again. To thing is it gives me the error at exactly the same point then before.

Comment: How many threads in your application? Do you able to edit source code in your case?

Comment: I belive there exist stack size configuration in Ubuntu, so it may override java configuration.

Comment: i am not able to overide the source code. I will have a look at the stack size configuration.

Comment: ubuntu has ulimit -s of 8096 by default while red hat has 6000. So i changed it to 10000 but the same error appears.